# ROR + CKEditor + PaperClip: uploading files with cyrillic names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, cyrillic

There is a CKEditor in my rails app working with Paperclip and Active Record. Works nicely but:

When uploading a file which contains cyrillic letters in filename, cyrillic letters are being cut (e.g. "документ_1_15.doc" becomes "_1_15.doc"). Nothing of this happens when uploading an image directly with Paperclip.
I tried to look into CKeditor code for answer, but couldn't find anything since CKEditor is being mounted as an Engine into the app.

p.s. Sorry for maybe a newbie question -- it's my first one on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in changing CKEditor gem files a bit.

The issue was in `[basename.parameterize('_'), extension].join.downcase` string in gem's /lib/ckeditor/utils.rb file (/home/*user*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/ckeditor-4.0.6/lib/ckeditor/utils.rb in my case). Unfortunately Ruby's **parametrize** function rejects cyrillic symbols, so I had to change in to `[basename.gsub(/\s/,'_'), extension].join.downcase` and it stopped cutting down cyrillics.